# Building an independent watchOS app using CMake

Tags: cmake, watchos

We are building an application that would be cross-platform and hence using CMake as the build system. While am able to build for iOS, macOS, tvOS etc, have not been able to build for watchOS using CMake. Right now, am looking for an independent watchOS app. Can someone help with any pointers or reference link for the same ?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?